# Why does clang boundless recursion terminate?

Tags: c++, gcc, recursion, clang, tail-recursion

With tail-call optimisation enabled via `-O2`, the following program runs endlessly using GCC, as expected. With Clang however, the program terminates, and outputs a value; apparently different each time. Does anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>

int rec()
{
  return 1 + rec();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int r;
  r = rec();
  std::cout << r << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler may assume your program terminates after a finite time, so if it doesn't, you are in the compilers hands. Not much more to say.

Comment: I think this is answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478078/clang-infinite-tail-recursion-optimization

Comment: There is a side-effect though, right? The result of the call to rec?

Comment: Your function is not tail-recursive.

Comment: A tail-recursive function has to return the result of the recursive call directly, it can't use it as the argument to another function or operator.